# Deploying node app on Digital Ocean with PM2

Tags: node.js, express, service, pm2

I'm trying to point a domain to my node app. To my understanding, this uses port 80 and im trying out PM2 to start my node app as a service. Typing `pm2 start app.js` returns a bunch of gibberish looking like this:

```
â"Oâ"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"¬â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?
â"' App name â"' id â"' mode â"' pid â"' status â"' restart â"' uptime â"' memory â"' watching â"'
â""â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"´â"?â"?â"?â"?â"´â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"?â"´â"?
```

I'm using express.js if that helps. Why is it spitting out this?

Digital Ocean droplet is running Linux 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminal doesn't support those characters.  Are you using Putty or something?

Try `babun` for a full-featured prompt on Windows.  That should allow you to ssh in to your Digital Ocean VPS without display issues.

Comment: I'm just using the standard windows 10 cmd